# Robot Framework : How to know whether a test library function is being executed from setup/test/teardown

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I have my own test library function run_test_routine()

I am calling the **same** function "Run Test Routine" as an RF Function from my RF suite in the setup section , test section and tear down section, like this

```
my RF test case
    [Setup]    Run Test Routine    setup_input
    Run Test Routine    test_input
    [Teardown]    Run Test Routine    teardown_input
```

Now , when this run_test_routine() gets invoked in the RF python library how do I get to know where it was called from ?
i.e was it called from the Setup section , test section or Teardown section ?

I would like to stress that this is required in the python code of the RF library and not in the text based RF suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a reliable way to determine the context in which a keyword is called. The only thing I can think of is to examine the stack to see if the internal routine `_run_setup` or `_run_teardown` was called. This could easily break in future versions of robot since it depends on the name of some private internal functions.

If you really want to do that, it might look something like this:

```
import traceback
def _is_setup():
    for tb in reversed(traceback.extract_stack()):
        if (tb[2] == "_run_setup"):
            return True
    return False

def _is_teardown():
    for tb in reversed(traceback.extract_stack()):
        if (tb[2] == "_run_teardown"):
            return True
    return False
```

I think the better solution is to have three keywords. Keep the one  you have, and then create two more called `Run Setup Test Routine` and `Run Teardown Test Routine`. They could both call the `Run Test Routine` function in addition to whatever special processing you need to do. Or, they could simply pass an extra argument to `Run Test Routine` to tell it the context.

Comment: Found a way to check whether its a teardown , by using the ${TEST STATUS} automatic variable, but couldnt find how to check whether the execution started from setup . Thanks alot for this the traceback solution haven't decided whether to use it or to use the custom setup/teardown solution